# Reliable keyboard layout switching with Caps Lock

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In my Ubuntu 15.10 I set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts in *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing > Switch to next source*.

But every time I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> it still capitalize keyboard for a split second (and Caps Lock LED blinks), then it back to non-capitalized keyboard and finally switch layout. But if I press any key after pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and before layout switching, the layout doesn't switches at all, and moreover my keyboard remain capitalized.

I very often switch keyboard between English and my native language, and typing very fast, so almost every third switching I capitalize keyboard instead of switching layout. It's very big trouble for me. Hot to fix it?

**Update (18 Sep 2016):** The bug is still exists in 16.04.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, however, after accidentally pressing the capslock key enough to thoroughly bug me, I removed the physical key. Now, if I want to turn the caps lock on or off, I have to press the internal button where the key used to be. This is a tradeoff I am willing to live with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Ubuntu 13.10,  Unity/Gnome moved the keyboard layout changing control from X server to higher level tool: `unity-settings-daemon`/`gnome-settings-daemon` plugin to add support for multiple X input methods. So the layout change function in X is just disabled.

Same for Caps key, X interprets it as capital lock. When you assign it to  layout changing in Unity settings. It will do both as X is not aware of that. So you have to disable caps function in X.

- The workaround explained in bug report mentioned by Alex.O seem to do that. Which is the same as running:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:none']"
  ```

  `caps:none` means *Caps Lock is disabled*, to see all Caps key X supported functions, try:

  ```
  more /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst | grep caps
  ```
- To get default function back:

  ```
  gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
  ```

Comment: It works! But unfortunately I can't more use the default feature of CapsLock.

Comment: I would like to see new upgrade of different input system like XIM and IBUS to support more events like long press on key or combination. That's allow us to make such multiple actions for same key.

Answer (score 5):

There is ancient bug on Launchpad, which contains workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1343327

Maybe it'll help. But it did not help to me (U 14.04.4).