# Modeless/stateless layout language switching with Caps Lock, again (18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver)

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard-layout, input-language, accessibility

This has been asked countless times, so I'll try to be brief.

I have **two input layouts**, Ukrainian and English, and want:

- to use **<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>** for fast switching;
- not have [any delays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969784/fast-switch-input-source-via-capslock-button-in-ubuntu-17-10) imposed, I'm a fast typer;
- not have [mode errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(user_interface)#Mode_errors):

  - (any number of) <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> sets English,
  - (any number of) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>CapsLock</kbd> sets Ukrainian;
- see the current layout in the standard widget.

I've already tried three (!) GUIs to configure this, the Gnome Settings, the `gnome-tweak-tool`, the `dconf-editor`/`gsettings`. Nothing works. `Tweaks` crashes randomly.

### Enough homework done

I've asked this myself [4 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370197/stateless-layout-switching-in-ubuntu-14-04) for 14.04 LTS. Since then, that UI popup appeared and all broke. I can now easily configure *stateful* <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> toggle, but even then, it goes with that irritating delay. Basically unusable at times when I need language switched 4-5 times per sentence.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727507/reliable-keyboard-layout-switching-with-caps-lock) suggests `caps:none` XKB option as a bug workaround. I've tried that, both with `gsettings` CLI and `dconf-editor`, and in combinations with **`grp:shift_caps_switch`** XKB option. No dice. Something trumps those core XKB features as it seems.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073893/configure-keyboard-shortcuts-to-capslock-and-shift-capslock-in-18-04-bionic-be) offers `caps:menu` XKB option as a hack to be able to bind <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in `Gnome Settings` → Devices → Keyboard. It kinda works, but A) it gives cyclic/stateful switching; B) I have to wait a decent timeout on every switch.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026964/how-can-i-switch-input-language-with-capslock-on-ubuntu-18-04) asks exactly what I need, yet it's unanswered and even worse: closed as duplicate of two other questions (???) none of which are the same, and none of which give me a working solution. What's wrong with you guys?

There's [another exact match](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056802/how-to-assign-caps-lock-first-lang-and-shiftcaps-lock-second-lang-in-ubuntu) — alas, unanswered as well!

---

#### Wanted: clean solution

Comment: What about reputation instead of $ for a bounty, let's say +50 points reputation?

Comment: @karel I see nothing wrong with that, however "fresh" questions are not eligible for rep bounty on stackexchange. [A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty); please un-downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote. All I did was commented.

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless, I did both [offered](https://askubuntu.com/users/9061/ulidtko?tab=bounties&sort=offered) and [earned](https://askubuntu.com/users/9061/ulidtko?tab=bounties&sort=earned) reputation bounties specifically on AskUbuntu. This question is going to get one, too, when it's time.

Comment: Monetary rewards and offers are **very much [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/should-i-edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward)** all over the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Care to explain the "*What's wrong with you guys*" part? Both the questions against which [the question you mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/q/1026964/480481) offer the same solution of using GNOME Tweaks and OP edited in the question that their problem was solved using Tweaks. Could you expand the "*none of which give me a working solution. What's wrong with you guys?*" part and explain *how exactly* it didn't work for you?

Comment: @pomsky, 1) Gnome Tweaks just crashes on checkbox flips at times, which I consider nearly "doesn't work" symptom by itself, 2) the `grp:shift_caps_switch`  checkbox in Tweaks, **right now being set on this system**, does *nothing:* i.e. no switching happens on capslock, with and without shift. The only thing happening is a brief blink of a keyboard LED (only with shift); *input layout stays the same*. Hence, you see, just mentioning "gnome-tweaks does it" isn't really a solution for me, that's why I'm frustrated and despite my best effort, occasionally leak that frustration via text. Sorry.

Comment: Caps_Lock generally doesn't work. If you're OK with another key sequence, I could write a solution that may do what you want. Will need some time, but can be done.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy capslock has worked fine since about 8.04 Hardy Heron AFAIR (but [got broken](/q/356357/9061) in 13.10). A solution/workaround with `xbindkeys` has been posted below. If you could look into why `gnome-tweaks` doesn't work as advertised (and crashes sometimes on checkbox flips)  — please do!

Comment: @ulidtko I'll try to take a peak at `gnome-tweaks-tool`. Won't promise if I can dig out anything and will need quite some time, since I'm busy lately, but I'll post an answer if I dig out anything related to `gnome-tweak-tool`. Feel free to leave me a comment here or contact me in other ways

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy hey, I've finally seen `apport` catch this gnome-tweaks crash; the autoreported LP bug is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool/+bug/1729962). Mind if we get together and collaborate on this, perhaps on Freenode IRC?..

Comment: @ulidtko  Sure, I'll attempt to contribute whatever I can. Just to put it forward, I've been a bit busy with work lately. I'll probably need to request access to the error portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meet **clean solution** that meets your needs:

[Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)). That's a GNOME Shell Extension and I am its author.

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout and that's it:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".

It **doesn't have any delays**, even the annoying language switch popup is not show.

It's **totally stateless and idempotent**. When you assign a D-Bus call (like the last one from the example above) for, say <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, any number of presses will set language to a deterministic value (German in the example).

It simply **works in recent GNOME versions** (I am using 42, but I've also tested on 45). Unlike the other solutions available in the Internet:

- The `setxkbmap` doesn't play nice with the GNOME Shell (it doesn't update the language in status area and simply breaks further layout switching until the next reboot).
- The `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore
- The `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …` is also deprecated due to security implications.

**Info for Nerds**: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) is based on D-Bus, but it doesn't use unsafe and deprecated `Eval` nor any of its alternatives. It re-implements a similar solution using [GJS](https://gjs.guide/) by accessing the same `getInputSourceManager` directly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd since switched to KDE, its stock `systemsettings` allows to configure this in a few clicks. But this extension will of course be useful to GNOME Shell users with similar needs. Well done!

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04, by default there is a option to choose <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> to achieve the behavior we are looking for, is in `gnome-tweaks`. But this is not working and could not get the reason why.

[image]

***I could manage to achieve this behavior by the below workaround.***

See this link for a 20Sec Video. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFSTt.jpg

first check the below commands in terminal whether they are changing the input language.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
```

and

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

well, they are working.

[image]

we need to bind these commands to key presses of <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd>

can achieve this with `xbindkeys` if xbindkeys is not yet installed install it by `sudo apt install xbindkeys`

1. create a file `.xbindkeysrc` in $HOME folder
   `touch ~/.xbindkeysrc`
2. to know the keycode/id what ever it is called
   run `xbindkeys --key` once the white box appears press the <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> button, do it for <kbd>Shift</kbd> button also and copy the keycodes/ids as show below

[image]

3. this step is Optional.. Disable the Caps Lock. See below gif. If caps lock is not disabled.. when you hit the key multiple times it will toggle while you try to change the language. I have Disabled it. but it is based on your interest.

[image]

4. Open the file `.xbindkeysrc`
   `gedit ~/.xbindkeysrc` and edit the file like below based on the results of above steps

Change the values in below content according to the results you got in step 2 above.
Content:

```
"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()""
m:0x10 + c:66

"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()""
Shift+Mod2 + Shift_L+m:0x10 + c:66
```

5. Save the file, Close & Reboot..

Comment: OMG it worked! I didn't even need to log-out, evenless reboot (`xbindkeys --poll-rc`). I also left `grp:shift_caps_switch` XKB option on — which changed how my key codes are printed (`m:0x0 + c:66` `ISO_First_Group` & `m:0x1 + c:66` `Shift + ISO_First_Group`); no problems from that. Even the keyboard LED shines! Amazing job, you totally should've get this bounty. (gnome-tweaks authors, whoever they are, get a grumpy frown from me & others.)

Comment: For older Ubuntu versions next commands for language switching works:
Switch to first layout:
_> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0_
Switch to second layout:
_> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1_

Comment: This solution does not change the layout in a super menu (when I hit the Super key and search for launching new applicaton)

Comment: Unfortunately step (4) above won't work.   Since Gnome-shell v41 (~Sept 2021) *dbus* no longer allows calling method `org.gnome.Shell.Eval` with arbitrary code due to [security concerns](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3943).

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug report you can subscribe to:

- [keyboard panel does not allow to set up Caps as input switch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1709562)

The bug report reads:

> Keyboard panel has options for input switching, but it does not allow
>   to use Caps as language switch.
>
> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1. gnome-control-center keyboard
> 2. Scroll down to 'Typing' section
> 3. Click on Switch to next input source
> 4. Press Caps
>
> Expected result: Caps Lock key is accepted as switch key Actual
>   results: Caps key is ignored in the selection window.
>
> P.S. Same goes for 'Switch to previous input source' and Shift-Caps
>   key combination.

## Bug Workarounds

The bug is currently on the "Wishlist". These workarounds are proposed:

### Workaround 1

Found a workaround for this bug:

1. Install dconf-editor (sudo apt-get install dconf-editor)
2. Go to /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/
3. Select key switch-input-source, turn off "Use default value" and set "Custom value" to ['Caps_Lock']
4. (Optional) You can also change value for switch-input-source-backward to something like ['Caps_Lock'] (again, turning off "Use default value")

### Workaround 2

Another way to do this:
1. Install GNOME Tweaks (gnome-tweak-tool)
2. Open the Tweaks app
3. Switch to the Keyboard & Mouse panel
4. Click Additional Layout Options
5. Use the "Switching to another layout" section

## Subscribe to bug report

I would recommend subscribing to the bug report and adding your own experiences. The more people subscribing to the bug report, the faster the solution comes (usually).

Comment: Workaround 1 doesn't suit my requirements, it gives **cyclic** switching, which is not what I want.  Workaround 2 (Gnome-Tweaks) has been tried and beaten to death; I can make it crash, but can't make it work. Thanks for (yet another) link though.

Answer (score 0):

For **using [CapsLock] to switch languages**, open the Gnome Tweaks tool (install it if not already there) and check *"Keyboard & Mouse" \ "Additional Layout Options" | "Switching to another layout" | "Caps Lock"*. [image]

For **eradicating the *popup* delay**, install the [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) Gnome-shell extension to avoid the switcher popup and switch languages instantaneously.  The extension does not define a *custom-shortcut*, so all customizations with `gnome-tweak-tool`/`setxkbmap` in X11 or *Wayland* still work fine, on all Gnome versions.

> **NOTE:** this solution does NOT address the "mode errors" (ie. when the switch key is pressed multiple times).

***Disclaimer**: I am the developer of the Quick Lang Switch...*