# Xbindkeys launches correctly application for the first time only

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, scripts, xbindkeys

When I put the following line in `~/.xbindkeysrc` GNOME correctly launches application `vlc`.

```
"vlc"
   XF86Calculator
```

The problem is that I'd like to run a shell script. When I put the following  in `~/.xbindkeysrc` GNOME doesn't launch my script but calculator.

```
"/home/menteith/bin/audio.sh"
   XF86Calculator
```

Why is that? The script is executable and works as expected when is run from command line.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @PRATAP I know know that when I use a compiled program in `~/.xbindkeysrc` (i.e. not a bash script) and press `XF86Calculator` button for the first time it launches my program, but when I press  `XF86Calculator` button for the second time I launches calculator instead.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to , @Raffa I tried yet another solution. I wrote a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  puts("Starting now:");
  system("killall -s1 xbindkeys; /home/menteith/bin/audio");
  return 0;
}
```

It kills `xbindkeys` and then runs wrapper, which in turn run the script. However, it still fails to work. After second time and next times `calculator` is being launched.

**UPDATE 3**
My script switched between audio from monitor (HDMI) and audio from PC.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output=$(pactl list cards |grep 'Active Profile:' | cut -d ':' -f 3)

if [ $output == "analog-stereo" ]; then
    out="hdmi-stereo"
else
    out="analog-stereo"
fi

echo test
# Set the choosen card profile as sink
pactl set-card-profile "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" "output:${out}"


# Set the default sink to the new one
pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3.${out}" &> /dev/null

# Redirect the existing inputs to the new sink
for i in $(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index | awk '{print $2}'); do
    pacmd move-sink-input "$i" "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3.${out}" &> /dev/null
done
```

Comment: @PRATAP Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Could you rephrase, please?

Comment: @PRATAP It works fine via `gnome-control-center keyboard`.

Comment: You can get debug output by running `xbindkeys -v -n`  Make sure your shell script is executable (`chmod a+x ...`).

Comment: @menteith I tried using `sh -c /home/user/script.sh` but it is only working for 1 time.. the next time calculator is getting opened.. something wrong..

Comment: I wrote a simple `C` program that launches my script and it also works for only 1 time. Curious.

Comment: menteith I forgot to ask you what is the Ubuntu version you are doing this?

Comment: @PRATAP I'm using latest, i.e. 19.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step # One:**

**Firstly:** I would suggest modifying the `~/.xbindkeysrc` file by clearing the file first then please copy and paste the following code into the file replacing `Key_Name` with your actual key name so it will look like this:

```
"sh /home/menteith/bin/audio.sh && killall -s1 xbindkeys"
Key_Name
```

**Secondly:** restart `xbindkeys` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
killall -s1 xbindkeys
```

**Finally:** try the configured key and see if it works as expected.

---

**Step # Two:**

Please inspect system settings under **Keyboard Shortcuts** like in the image below:

[image]

If there is a hot key configured for **Launch calculator** here, then it should be disabled. Otherwise, it might interfere with `xbindkeys` and capture the hot-key press preventing your script from running and running the calculator instead.

---

**Step # Three:**

Another place to look into is the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file.

**Firstly:** open the file in the `gedit` editor by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

**Secondly:** look for a line that contains `XF86Calculator` in it. It will look something like this:

```
key  <Key_Name> {   [XF86Calculator]    };
```

Comment out this line by adding a `//` before it like this:

```
//key  <Key_Name> { [XF86Calculator]    };
```

Take note of the **Key_Name** in `<Key_Name>` and save and close the file.

**Thirdly:** edit your `~/.xbindkeysrc` file replacing `XF86Calculator` with the noted **Key_Name** in step **Secondly** above. It should look like this:

```
"sh /home/menteith/bin/audio.sh && killall -s1 xbindkeys"
Key_Name
```

Save and close the file.

**Fourthly:** Clear the xkb settings cache by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

**Fifthly:** reboot your system to activate your new xkb configuration or reload the new xkb configuration by setting an xkb map layout using the following command in the terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

**Finally:** start `xbindkeys` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Then try your Hot-Key. If nothing happens, restart `xbindkeys` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
killall -s1 xbindkeys
```

Now, try your Hot-Key again and see if it works as expected.

Best Of Luck

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick. You are very welcome to come up with another solution. Btw, Please see my updated question.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I tried you solution but with no luck.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: `F3` works fine (with my C program). BTW, when `xev` is running, it doesn't show output (print keycode) when I press `XF86Calculator` key.

Comment: I don't have FF installed but I tried `google-chrome-stable` (if needed I can try with FF, thought). Calculator is launched instead of Chrome (I tried `google-chrome-stable` as well as full path to the executable).

Comment: I would rather say thank you for your patience. I had (and still have) disabled hot key that launches calculator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Upvoted as it almost does the trick - it works but after n presses (10, 20, cannot tell) it stops and runs calculator.

Answer (score 1):

***Workaround***

Tried it on Ubuntu 19.10

contents of `myscript.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

notify-send "Script Ran Successfully"
```

contents of `.xbindkeysrc` file.

```
"/bin/bash $HOME/myscript.sh"
XF86Calculator
```

Once you logged in,

run `xbindkeys --poll-rc`. the key XF86Calculator should run your script.

Reference for --poll-rc option https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys and see the comment below the answer in this link https://askubuntu.com/a/1126410/739431

[image]