# Writing a script to be called with keyboard press

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, keyboard, brightness, xrandr

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 15 7590. As you may know, my model has an OLED screen. Screen brightness functionality does not work so when I am using the intel card, I have to enter this in the terminal:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
```

And when I am using my NVIDIA card, I have to enter this:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.5
```

Is there a way I can write a script that will be invoked whenever I press `Fn + F10/F11` to control the brightness? Here is a pseudocode of what I am talking about:

```
if card = intel:
   xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
else:
   xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.5
```

`Fn + F10` is supposed to increase brightness. `Fn + F11` is supposed to decrease the brightness.

Comment: I don't know about Gnome, but in Xfce it is easy to add keyboard shortcuts in Keyboard dialog. You would write a shell script in a file and write its path in the dialog.

Comment: As for checking which card you are using, see other questions such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/68028/21005) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16407/111181).

Comment: Do you know any scripting? [This](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start) is one good starting point for learning Bash scripting.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185518/xbindkeys-launches-correctly-application-for-the-first-time-only/1187061#1187061